# How can I delete all the properties of a particular node using a cypher query on Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

I need to get the exisiting properties of a node and delete all the node properties excluding `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is actually to set a map on the node (this replaces the properties of the node with the properties in the map, and ensuring the map only contains the projected properties you want to keep:

```
MATCH (n:person)
WITH n, n {.id, ._int_version} as propsToKeep
SET n = propsToKeep
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer on https://markhneedham.com/blog/2019/03/14/neo4j-delete-dynamic-properties/

```
MATCH (n:person)
WITH n, [k in keys(n) where not k in ["id","_int_version"]] as keys
CALL apoc.create.removeProperties(n, keys) YIELD node
RETURN node;
```